# Problems with EAR deployment in weblogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I'm having a problem trying to deploy WAR files within an Enterprise Application on Weblogic.

The Web applications work fine as individual .war files when deployed, but when bundled together in an .ear file there seems to be a problem accessing resources in each web application's WEB-INF/classes directory.

I have some resources that need to be accessed from this directory (for example a log4j.xml file). When the .ear file is deployed, Weblogic unpacks it to tmp location on the server. Everything seems correct, except that the WEB-INF/classes directory has none of the expected files in it. They exist inside the .war file in the .ear file.

Files at the WEB-INF and WEB-INF/lib directory and the WEB-INF and the base directory for the .war file all exist, but the WEB-INF/classes directory is mysteriously empty.

The ClassLoader for Weblogic indicates that the path for this directory is on the classpath, but with no files, it obviously can't find them.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like a build problem. How are you building the EAR file and component WAR files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after much head scratching, it seems to have been a problem with the Version in the application.xml, for some reason when set to "jee5" Weblogic (10.3.6) was not expanding anything in WEB-INF/classes directory.

Files were definitely there, but not being extracted from the .war file within the ear file.

Switching to version "1.4" fixed the problem.

Comment: The `version` element of an application.xml file must be one of `1.4` or `5`. Anything else is illegal and probably resulted in deployment failure

Comment: True enough, that seems to have been the issue. I'm not sure where I got the version jee5 from.

Answer (score 0):

why because weblogic bundled all classes into _wl_cls_gen.jar. so that in class path have to mention this path directory from our application.

**For example:**

```
    classpath.append("." + pathSeperator + path + File.separator +"lib"+ 
    File.separator+"_wl_cls_gen.jar" + pathSeperator);
```

Hope this helpful.